# Error code ElasticPoolOverStorageUsage

Tags: sql, azure-sql

I'm trying to create a new database in our Azure SQL elastic pool and getting the following error code.

```
    Error code: ElasticPoolOverStorageUsage.
```

We have a total space of 32GB and based on the Elastic pool data storage graph, we have used only 65% of its total storage, leaving us with another 35% i.e.11GB.
I'm trying to create a new blank database and not getting anywhere.

I would appreciate any idea where I'm going wrong.

Answer (score 0):

The error is pretty clear:

```
400 ElasticPoolOverStorageUsage - Attempting to write data to a database when the storage limit of the elastic pool has been reached.
```

If you really have used only the 65% contact Microsoft Support.

And share the answer, I'm intrigued.